# Code::Blocks w/ MinGW: statically link libpng into a dll

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, codeblocks, libpng

I'm trying to link `libpng16.lib` to my .dll file but I cannot get it to work. I included already `libpng16.lib` and `zlib.lib` into project dependencies (in right order, libpng first) but still get to `png_*` linking errors.

Even other's solution I search in the google won't work.

**Edit:**

Here's the log:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall  -O2  -std=c++11 -Wall -g    -c C:\Users\Mark\Documents\CodeBlocks\TextureLoader\TextureLoader.cpp -o obj\Release\TextureLoader.o
C:\Users\Mark\Documents\CodeBlocks\TextureLoader\TextureLoader.cpp: In static member function 'static unsigned int TextureLoader::PNG_Texture_Load(const char*)':
C:\Users\Mark\Documents\CodeBlocks\TextureLoader\TextureLoader.cpp:105:21: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
mingw32-g++.exe -shared  -Wl,--out-implib=bin\Release\libTextureLoader.a -Wl,--dll -LC:\MinGW\include  obj\Release\TextureLoader.o   -o bin\Release\TextureLoader.dll -lOpenGL32 -lGLu32 -s  C:\Users\Mark\Documents\CodeBlocks\TextureLoader\libpng16.lib C:\Users\Mark\Documents\CodeBlocks\TextureLoader\libpng16.lib 
obj\Release\TextureLoader.o: In function `ZN13TextureLoader16PNG_Texture_LoadEPKc':
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:27: undefined reference to `png_sig_cmp'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:33: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:41: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:50: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:59: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:66: undefined reference to `png_init_io'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:68: undefined reference to `png_set_sig_bytes'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:70: undefined reference to `png_read_info'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:77: undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:79: undefined reference to `png_read_update_info'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:81: undefined reference to `png_get_rowbytes'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:109: undefined reference to `png_read_image'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:123: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/TextureLoader/TextureLoader.cpp:100: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
```

Comment: Can you post the link command used by codeblocks + errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Undefined symbols during linking usually indicates there's something wrong with the import libraries you're trying to link against or there's a disagreement between what the toolset is looking for and what symbols the import actually provides.

Having said that, the gnu ld linker that comes with mingw should be able to understand msvc `.lib` import libraries. As an alternative you can try linking directly against the `libpng16.dll` by passing that to the linker.

For example, try linking with this command:

> g++.exe -shared -Wl,--out-implib=bin\Release\libTextureLoader.a -LC:\MinGW\include  obj\Release\TextureLoader.o -o bin\Release\TextureLoader.dll -lOpenGL32 -lGLu32 path\location\of\your\libpng16.dll

Note that `-LC:\MinGW\include` in your original link command is probably not right. The library path directly containing the runtime and various other imports usually reside somewhere in mingw's lib directory rather than in the include directory. For example, mines is in `G:\Mingw32-4.6.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib`.

Comment: I try to replace linker options with the .dll one but it says 'no such file or directory'. Anyway, I already solve this problem by rebuilding again libpng16 myself but get me to another error. `zlib-sgd-x86.dll` is missing. I can't find this dll in the internet. Maybe I just mess up something here.

Comment: In my response, I was assuming that you're trying to link against the dll version of libpng and not a statically compiled version. Make sure you pass the fully qualified path of where your `libpng.dll` actually resides.